# golang testing command line arguments

Tags: go

I want to test different (correct/incorrect) command line arguments passed to my CLI program, but I am not sure how to achieve this with go/testing package because I am getting `flag redefined` error. Looks like it happens because `flag.Parse()` can be called only once. What is the proper approach to test different command line arguments passed into the go program? Is there is any way to define something like `setup()/teardown()` or run every case in isolation (but in the same file)?

Here is my code:

Function to test:

```
func (p *Params) Parse() (*Params, error) {
        param1Ptr := flag.String("param1", "default", "param1 desc")
        param2Ptr := flag.String("param2", "default", "param1 desc")
        ...
        ... 
        flag.Parse()
        ...

}
```

Test file:

package main

```
import (
        "os"
        "testing"
)


func TestParam1(t *testing.T) {
        os.Args = []string{"cmd", "-param1", "incorrect", "-param2", "correct"}
        params := Params{}
        _, err := params.Parse()
        ...
        ... 
}

func TestParam2(t *testing.T) {
        os.Args = []string{"cmd", "-param1", "correct", "-param2", "incorrect"}
        params := Params{}
        _, err := params.Parse()
        ...
        ... 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use the global `FlagSet` object in the `flags` package. Create your own `FlagSet` as a field of `Params`: https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#FlagSet

All that `flag.String` et al do is pass through the function call to a global `FlagSet` object in the `flag` package (specifically `flag.CommandLine` is the variable). This is easy to use but not a generally good practice. Using your own flagset would avoid the issues you described as well as other potential side effects from using global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the global FlagSet before each test using:

```
flag.CommandLine = flag.NewFlagSet(os.Args[0], flag.ExitOnError)
```

See [How to unset flags Visited on command line in GoLang for Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57969637/how-to-unset-flags-visited-on-command-line-in-golang-for-tests)